# share on linkedin returns "Can not parse JSON share document"

Tags: meteor, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am trying to share a post on linkedin.

I managed to log in and get returned an `id` and an `accessToken` but when I follow the REST APIs way of [sharing an update](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin) I keep getting:

```
Error: failed [400] {
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Can not parse JSON share document.\nRequest body:\n\nError:\nnull",
  "requestId": "NWGE7D4LSW",
  "status": 400,
  "timestamp": 1451699447711
}
```

My http POST looks like this:

```
HTTP.post('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json&oauth2_access_token=' + accessToken, {
            'headers': {
              'Content-Type': "application/json",
              'x-li-format': "json"
            },
            'comment': "test!",
            'visibility': {
              'code': "anyone"
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked:

```
      HTTP.post('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json&oauth2_access_token=' + Meteor.user().services.linkedin.accessToken, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "x-li-format": "json"
        },
        data: {
          comment: "testing",
          visibility: {
            code: "anyone"
          }
        }
      });
```